# multiregex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, bulk

I am trying to test a large group regexes, and I am worried about performance.

Specifically, I am using [crawler-user-agents](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crawler-user-agents) to treat bots differently. Checking with `performance.now()`, it takes about 1ms to check the whole array. Not too bad, but I don't want to add this time to my site.

```js
const bots = require('crawler-user-agents');
const patterns = bots.map(x => RegExp(x.pattern))

function middleware(req, res, next){
    const { headers = {} } = req;
    const userAgent = headers['user-agent'];

    if(userAgent && patterns.some(x => x.test(userAgent)){
        return next();
    }

    //regular code
    //...
}
```

So, I want some way to merge down these regexes to a smaller array, or a single combined regex.
I found this library in Java: https://github.com/fulmicoton/multiregexp

1) Is there an equivalent for js?
2) Even static union could work, is there a service where I could pre-compress my patterns into a smaller set?

Comment: Please, post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: added MCVE. thanks :)

Comment: Please note that asking for a library or service is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is currently not such a feature available in EcmaScript `RegExp` instances.

Some libraries provide additional features, like [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com). This one has [`XRegExp.union`](http://xregexp.com/api/#union). However, that function does not seem to really optimise the merge of the individual regexes, so `abcde` and `abcdE` will be merged as `abcde|abcdE`, while `abcd[eE]` would have been a more efficient unified regex. That "simple" union could still lead to a performance gain though.

Note that the Java library [multirexp](https://github.com/fulmicoton/multiregexp) you linked to has no support for groups. If indeed you don't need support for that, then you can achieve a simple merge with this line of code:

```
const unifiedPattern = RegExp(bots.map(x => `(?:${x.pattern})`).join("|"));
```

Again, this will not further optimise the resulting regex.

Comment: I tried manually grouping using ```.map(pattern => `(${pattern})`).join('|')```. The improvement was insignificant. :S

Comment: I can imagine that. The theoretical time complexity does not improve with such a union. To really get an advantage, the regexes have to be parsed together in order to make an efficient new regex. Doing that in JavaScript itself could be a costly operation (apart from being non-trivial). Our hope could be that some day EcmaScript will be extended with such a feature.